# Postfix config under ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-14.04

My dedicated server is running ubuntu 14.04.
It's also configured as a dns server (bind) and my domain **toto.be** is pointing on it.

I also installed postfix, added mx record, add iptables rules to open input port 53 (udp + tcp).

Ok, now I'm testing.

- On my server I can send an email to local user root
- On my server I can send an email to external email address (myname@gmail.com)
- From gmail, I **can't** send an email to root@toto.be

In my log

```
Oct  2 14:45:35 mail postfix/smtpd[31278]: connect from mail-qc0-x22b.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c01::22b]
Oct  2 14:45:36 mail postfix/smtpd[31278]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-qc0-x22b.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c01::22b]: 454 4.7.1 <root@toto.be>: Relay access denied; from=<myname@gmail.com> to=<root@toto.be> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-qc0-x22b.google.com>
Oct  2 14:45:36 mail postfix/smtpd[31278]: disconnect from mail-qc0-x22b.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c01::22b]
```

In my **main.cf** I try adding google.com to mynetworks but I don't think it is the solution (what for all others domains ?)

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 google.com
```

Now the message is accepted but cannot be delivered

```
Oct  2 14:49:09 mail postfix/smtpd[31484]: connect from mail-qg0-x231.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c04::231]
Oct  2 14:49:10 mail postfix/smtpd[31484]: 541357F836: client=mail-qg0-x231.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c04::231]
Oct  2 14:49:10 mail postfix/cleanup[31489]: 541357F836: message-id=<CAA-VCPUqg9XmmJGhH5oFAZv5d0FfnLMg4idPwmXkB2CRw@mail.gmail.com>
Oct  2 14:49:10 mail postfix/qmgr[31437]: 541357F836: from=<myname@gmail.com>, size=1754, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  2 14:49:10 mail postfix/smtp[31490]: 541357F836: to=<root@toto.be>, relay=none, delay=0.31, delays=0.3/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for toto.be loops back to myself)
Oct  2 14:49:10 mail postfix/cleanup[31489]: 8EC927F83A: message-id=<20141002124910.8EC927F83A@smtp.toto.be>
Oct  2 14:49:10 mail postfix/bounce[31491]: 541357F836: sender non-delivery notification: 8EC927F83A
Oct  2 14:49:10 mail postfix/qmgr[31437]: 8EC927F83A: from=<>, size=3676, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  2 14:49:10 mail postfix/qmgr[31437]: 541357F836: removed
Oct  2 14:49:10 mail postfix/smtpd[31484]: disconnect from mail-qg0-x231.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c04::231]
Oct  2 14:49:11 mail postfix/smtp[31490]: 8EC927F83A: to=<myname@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c02::1b]:25, delay=1, delays=0.03/0/0.17/0.83, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1412254151 m13si5148612wjw.140 - gsmtp)
Oct  2 14:49:11 mail postfix/qmgr[31437]: 8EC927F83A: removed
```

What can I do ?

```
postconf -n

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = smtp.toto.be, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = smtp.toto.be
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 google.com
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated     defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

/etc/mailname

```
toto.be
```

Comment: Please post the output of `postconf -n`

Comment: Ok the question is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you are only allowing email meant for smtp.toto.be; nowhere is there a mention that you accept delivery for toto.be, so...

```
myhostname = smtp.toto.be
mydomain = toto.be
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, $mynetworks, localhost, localhost.localdomain 
myorigin = $mydomain
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks Avery Payne.  Now it's working fine !  Now I just have to create my mailboxes and install dovecot.

Answer (score -1):

One thing to do is in postfix.conf make sure that you have 'myorigin' set to your domain of toto.be so that local users are mapped to @toto.be.  This can be done a couple ways:

```
myorigin = $mydomain
```

(if you have $mydomain set somewhere ), or:

```
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

(if you have a file called /etc/mailname with toto.be as the first line), or even explicitly like:

```
myorigin = toto.be
```

Also, the error '(mail for toto.be loops back to myself)' indicates that something is messed up with routing.  I had this problem once and found that removing 'relayhost = $myhostname' from postfix.conf fixed it.

Reference:  http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myorigin

Comment: It's already done.  Second solution.  But /etc/mailname contents toto.be and not myorigign = toto.be